# Firebase rules Validation failed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have users lookup looks like this: contains [username] [uid] [image]

I want to make username only contains characters and numbers.

```js
"user_lookup": {
  ".read": "auth !== null",
  "$username": {   
    ".write": "!data.exists()",
    ".validate": " 
      newData.val().matches(/^[a-z][a-z0-9]*([._-][a-z0-9]+)*$/) &&
      newData.isString()",
      "$uid": {
        ".validate": "newData.val() == auth.uid"
      },
```

I'm getting Validation failed. If I add validate it will get failed doesn't matter what is inside.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Simulator screenshot:

[image: Simulator screenshot]

Comment: @CNuts $uid works fine, validate at $username not working im getting validation failed, I want to make "user_lookup" wont create childs if it doesn't contain characters and numbers only.

Comment: Can you show the code (or a screenshot from the simulator) that shows: the value being written, the location it's being written to, and the auth data?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Alright here you are https://i.gyazo.com/efc25cf15694e87da090ce226adbae44.png and if i removed validate it success https://i.gyazo.com/d33fa4158ae00d9cf4a7d2a5791810e9.png But i want to write only characters and numbers for the username.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're writing a JSON object:

```
{
    "wewe": "xxxa"
}
```

So both part of your validation will fail: a JSON object is neither a string not does it match the regex.

To make the validation work, write a string value that matches our regex:

```
"xxxa"
```

Comment: Its fail anyway https://i.gyazo.com/c0391fce9467f123179e23bd9f62858f.png I think Childs cannot add validation there, Thanks for your help, I'll try another method to do that. Which is switch between uid and username like this: https://i.gyazo.com/46c48dc94d75e8c508d70cde94c575a6.png

Comment: In your first screenshot, you still write a complex JSON object. That means that **`newData.val()` is not a string** so you cannot call `length` on it.

Comment: so that's mean I cannot validation to make username length atleast 4 chars? until i change to another method as shown in second screenshot right?